# iOS : Error when I read a video from Google Drive a certain amount of times

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, google-drive-api

When I read videos in my iOS application which it uses the Google Drive API, at a certain time of reading a video, I have this error : Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=403 "(null)"
And I can read the other videos until a certain amount of times, when I still have this error.

Here is my code :

```
if ([file.mimeType isEqualToString:@"video/quicktime"])
{

    GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:file.downloadUrl];

    [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString* accessToken = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"];
            player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&access_token=%@",file.downloadUrl,accessToken]]];
            [[player view] setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-150, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height+30, 300, 400)];
            player.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&access_token=%@",file.downloadUrl,accessToken]];
            [player setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&access_token=%@",file.downloadUrl,accessToken]]];
            [player setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];


            player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
            player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
            player.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;

            [self.view addSubview: [player view]];
            [player play];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Is it a cause of the amount of data downloaded ? Did I forget anything to enable or disable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use `GTMHTTPFetcher` but If your problem is about `HTTPStatus Code=403` , it's forbidden to access the service. So you can't do anything in this case. You should show a message to user when they try to reach forbidden video. 
You can check the statusCode

```
if(HTTPStatusCode == 403){
   //Show an alertView to user
}
```

or you should control video which has permissions. Otherwise your app will crash.

More info about [HTTP status code 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

Checking other status code will clear your application.
Status are so important to fetch data. If something went wrong you should check it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I will do that, but what do you use instead of GTMHTTPFetcher ?

Comment: I use `NSURLSession`, but using `GTMHTTPFetcher` also be fine.